# Trying to deploy the meteor application on galaxy

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to deploy the meteor application on galaxy.
These are the steps i am doing:

```
set DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com 
meteor deploy utmonthlyres.meteorapp.com --settings ./settings.json
```

Error:

```
Talking to Galaxy servers at: https://galaxy.meteor.com
Error deploying application: Server error (please try again later)
```

Comment: I do not see region in your hostname url, try this: `set DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=us-east-1.galaxy-deploy.meteor.com`

Comment: Seeing the same problem. @Khang suggestion did not help. I'm on my 3rd day waiting for a response from Galaxy Support.